# GTk and open GL Not working at compile time

Tags: opengl, gtk, gtk3

I am trying to make an application using Gtk 3 and OpenGl but when I try to compile the file, the Gl commands are not recognized. Any suggestions? Code and Errors provided below. I am just trying to setup and render a empty gl area.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

static gboolean
render (GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context)
{
 glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);  


  return TRUE;
}


static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data){
    GtkWidget *window;
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Calculator");
    gtk_window_resize(GTK_WINDOW(window), 290, 300);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);


    GtkWidget *gl = gtk_gl_area_new();
    g_signal_connect (gl, "render", G_CALLBACK(render), NULL);


    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("com.calculate", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc OpenGl.c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o gl `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Error Message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmKOqOJ.o: in function `render':
OpenGl.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `glClearColor'
/usr/bin/ld: OpenGl.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `glClear'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Why aren't you searching for OpenGL with `pkg-config` too?

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: You forgot to add the gl widget to the window. Add `gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), gl)` before gtk_widget_show_all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link OpenGL with your program, just like you have linked GTK+. `-lOpenGL` in your compiler invocation may be all you need.